# log axis display without transformation of data in ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2

p=ggplot(df, aes(x=logcon, y=res)) +
geom_jitter(aes(y= (res),color=TRTGRP), width = 0, shape=1,size=1,height = 0.01) +
geom_smooth(method="glm", se=T, method.args = list(family=binomial))+ theme_bw()+
+scale_x_continuous(breaks = 10^x)

I want to use geom_smooth with log10(x) and y data and just want to just display x axis in original scale as 1,10,100,1000 without affecting geom_smooth curve. All i attempted changing the curve also. can you please suggest any idea?  OR

with linear x,y, then  log scale x display only no transformation of geom_smooth curve.

Comment: (A) this is not a statistics question.  (B) it would be a better question with some data. (C) some of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699493/transform-only-one-axis-to-log10-scale-with-ggplot2 may help